# ngRouting issues in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have login and sign-up form. I have defined login and sign-up js code in one main controller. If user is new , I have defined link below the login , on-click of url it should get re-directed to another html page. URl is getting routed, but my js code is not responding . I tried to rectify the mistake, but i couldn't achieve it.

Please let me know what mistake, I have done. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

AngularJS code :

```
var app = angular.module('logapp',['toastr','ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/login',{
    templateUrl : "login.html",
    controller : "credientials"
})      
.when('/signup',{
    templateUrl : "signup.html",
    controller : "signctrl"
})
.when('/practice',{
    templateUrl : "practice.html",
    controller : "practicectrl"
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

Controller code :

```
1. app.controller('credientials',['$scope','$route','$rootScope','$window','$location','$http','toastr','Authentication',function($scope,$route,$rootScope,$window,$location,$http,toastr,Authentication) 

2. app.controller('signctrl',function($scope){});
    app.controller('head',function($scope){
    $scope.hometitle = "Create your account here. It's take only a minute."
});

1. Login controller
2. Signup controller
```

Comment: what version are you using and how do you type the link url related route?

Comment: version is 1.6.4.  `<div ng-controller="footerctr"> <p>{{footer}}<a href="/signup"> Here </a></p>
 </div>` @GurkanYesilyurt

Comment: try invoke with hashprefix <a href="#!/signup">  if you don't use HTML5 mode.

Comment: honestly not very clear, the code provided is not complete... can you please provide plunker??

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt ... I just invoked your function , but still my js code is not responding

Comment: @hr-tis . If it's possible , I'll try to create it.  Because my code is too lengthy

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt.  Thanks my code is working . There was typo mistake , that's why i got error

Comment: @SRK you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use HTML5 mode you should specify hash-prefix.

And with Angular 1.6;

> The default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang URLs has changed
>   from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!').

So, you can use the URL as below by default :

```
<a href="#!signup">
```

Also check: [Angular 1.6 $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)